# Add UITableView to Sidebar programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i created a custom class to add a sidebar to some of my MainTableViewControllers. If the user click on the MainTableRow the sidebar should open and show some detail Information in another UITableView. So i need to create a UITableView in my sidebar View. There should be some different Custom Cells for this new table.

My Problem is, that there is no data shown in my Table. The cells are always empty. Do i need to set on init anything else to tell the TableViewController where he find his UITableViewDataSource?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code atm:

```
class SideView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

On init i load my TableView into my View:

```
init(view: UIView) {

    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: 150, height: view.frame.size.height-40))

    var tvc:UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 768), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    addSubview(tvc)

....

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleLabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SideLabelTitleTableViewCell

    cell.titleText = "Hello Test"

    return cell

....
```

And this is my Custom Cell atm:

```
var titleText:String!

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "TitleLabelCell")
    // Initialization code

    var titleLabel:UILabel!
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,150,44)
    titleLabel.text = titleText

    self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
}
```

**Edit: Ok now the datasource should work, but i am unable to use my UITableViewCell.**

I use:

```
tvc.dataSource = self
```

But when i try to set a value from my sideViewClass for "titleLabel" it is always "nil". If i set it from my CustomCellClass it works as expected:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "TitleLabelCell")

    var labelText:String!

    println(self.labelText)

    var titleLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,150,44))

    titleLabel.text = self.labelText // THIS IS NOT WORKING, always nil?

    self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

And set my cell value with on cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    cell.labelText = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to implement class in proper syntax:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
   var titleLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0))
   var labelText: String! {
       willSet {
           titleLabel.text = newValue
       }
   }
   init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
       super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "TitleLabelCell")
       contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
   }
}
```

do not declare external var/let in methods

and one more thing, if you're going to use XIB/storyboard, use `awakeFromNib()` instead of `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String)`

Comment: Thanks. I do this already and the Label is still shown. But i am unable to set the value for my titleLabel from cellForRowAtIndexPath. Always gets "nil". Do you have any idea?

Comment: yes, you shouldn't use var labelText:String!, do cell.titleLabel.text = someText in cellForRowAtIndexPath: instead

Comment: or you can use var labelText:String { willSet { titleLabel.text = newValue } }

Comment: @derdida I updated my answer, should work for you now

Comment: Thank you: But still get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - if i create a IBOutlet for my Label.  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel! and on init with:  var titleLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,150,44)) - do i need anything else (normally i use Interface Builder to connect my Outlets, but this is created programmatically)

Comment: then try to do not use @IBOutlet

Comment: var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleLabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SideLabelTitleTableViewCell
cell.titleLabel.text = "test"
return cell

Comment: @derdida see my answer updates, should help, replace configuring code from init to awakeFromNib

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is working now as i want to.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Custom Cell Class To :

```
var titleLabel:UILabel!
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "TitleLabelCell")
    // Initialization code

    titleLable = UILable()
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,150,44)

    self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
}
```

And Then

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TitleLabelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SideLabelTitleTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = "Hello Test"

    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate and datasource, then reload the table.

```
tvc.delegate = self
tvc.dataSource = self
tvc.reloadData()
```

Also register the tableview cell with the table

```
tvc.registerClass(SideLabelTitleTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier:"TitleLabelCell")
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my Question. There is still a problem to set my value for my Labels in Cell. Do i really need to reload (because i set it on ViewDidLoad, so normally it should work without reload it, or?)

Comment: The reload makes sure the table gets filled when first setup.